# How to convert a Java TreeMap to a Scala SortedMap?

Tags: scala

Following along with chapters and examples in "Scala for the Impatient", there's an exercise related to using a Java `TreeMap` as a Scala `SortedMap`.  In the scala shell, I tried this:

```
var t: scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Int] = new java.util.TreeMap[String,Int]()
```

but I get an error message about type mismatch.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Note: I did an import of `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` and then did this:

```
var t: SortedMap[String,Int] = TreeMap[String,Int]()
```

This works, but variable `t` has type `java.util.SortedMap`, not `scala.collection.SortedMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read that book, but you need to make your mind up. Is `t` a Scala `SortedMap` or is it a Java `TreeMap`?

A `TreeMap` isn't a `SortedMap`, so you can't assign one to a `SortedMap` variable without converting it. `JavaConversions` will do some conversions for you, including:

```
implicit def mapAsScalaMap [A, B] (m: Map[A, B]): Map[A, B]
   Implicitly converts a Java Map to a Scala mutable Map.
```

However there's nothing to convert to a `SortedMap`.

If this conversion seems mysterious to you, the library designers would agree, so `JavaConversions` is deprecated in Scala 2.10, in favour of `JavaConverters`, which requires a specific `.asScala` method to do a conversion.

Unfortunately `JavaConverters` doesn't have anything to produce a `SortedMap` either (`.asScala` gives you a `mutable.Map`). So you need to rebuild the collection using its elements.

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.SortedMap
var t: SortedMap[String, Int] =
    SortedMap[String, Int]() ++ new java.util.TreeMap[String,Int].asScala
```

Producing a new TreeMap in the code above is obviously a bit pointless because it's empty, but you should get the idea of how to deal with an existing one. If you don't have an existing one, just produce a new `SortedMap` in Scala.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.  I thought I could produce a scala SortedMap "view" of a Java TreeMap, but I guess that is not possible.  The .asScala conversion to a mutable.Map may be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
import collection._
import JavaConverters._

var t: scala.collection.SortedMap[String,Int] = 
    new java.util.TreeMap[String,Int]().asScala.map(identity)(breakOut)
```

Comment: I believe this creates a copy of the TreeMap as opposed to a view (so when the original TreeMap is modified, the copy won't show that).