# Play Framework (java) - Treemap.zipWithIndex sorting order not preserved

Tags: java, scala, sorting, playframework

I'm using the Play Framework for java (2.5.4 with scala 2.11.8). I have a java.util.TreeMap (with a Comparable key) correctly sorted when getting out of my controller, but when using the zipWithIndex function on the view side, the sorting order is not preserve and the map is traversed in the insertion order. However, I need the index of the element in that loop too. Any idea why the zipWithIndex does not preserve the order (even if the javadoc says so), or any other suggestions to have loop counter in my scala template?

In the scala head, I have a variable defined as (the MyComparableKey implements the Comparable interface, no problem when doing a foreach on it, everything stays sorted).

```
results : java.util.Map[MyComparableKey, java.util.List[MyValue]]
```

and inside de template, I'm using it with:

```
@for(((k, values), i) <- results.zipWithIndex) {
     @* the keys are traversed in insertion order *@
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `zipWithIndex` method is provided via an implicit conversion to a Scala Iterable. My suspect is that some information is lost regarding the concrete type while doing the conversion. Do you think you can make a try with `scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap` and see if that works? Perhaps this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151607/how-to-convert-a-java-treemap-to-a-scala-sortedmap

Comment: Tried to explicitelly convert in the scala template as specified in your link with no success... I needed the index because I have a form object with a list of complex objects and used the index to know which list (from form) I had to show regarding each key. I finally used an extra list that keeps the mapping between the list index and the map key (pretty nasty, but could not find another way)